# How to use autofill in Google Sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have formula to auto fill data like column A. It is no need to hand dragging or auto filling by suggestion.

[image]

Here column A is perfectly done. Cell A1 formula as below:

```
={ "VendorNo"; unique(General!A2:A) }
```

Cell B1 formula is correct as below:

```
LOOKUP(VendorStatus!A2,sort(General!A2:A),sort(General!C2:C,General!A2:A,TRUE))
```

Once cell A1 is done, all A column is real auto filled. All I want is to do is the same effect like cell A1. How can I rewrite B1 formula to auto filled the rest B column value?

P.S.: I am sorry I couldn't post image above directly because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in B1 (assuming your formula gives you the right answer)

```
={"EventStartDate";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,LOOKUP(A2:A,sort(General!A:A),sort(General!C:C,General!A:A,TRUE))))}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike Steelson. You save me a day.

Answer (score 0):

try in row 1:

```
={"event start date"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, General!A2:C, 3, 0)))}
```

or:

```
={"event start date"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
  SORT(General!A2:C, ROW(General!A2:C), 0), 3, 0)))}
```

Comment: Hello player0, Your solution is very close. But I want to get the last record. So vlookup cannot fulfil the result. However. I try formula like below cannot be done. any thoughts? : ={"event start date"; INDEX(IFNA(LOOKUP(VendorStatus!B2,sort(General!B2:B),sort(General!D2:D,General!B2:B,TRUE))))}

Comment: @HomeShare in that case instead of `General!A2:C` use `SORT(General!A2:C, ROW(General!A2:C), 0)`